# Using Net::FTP instance method `open` for FTP with custom port

Tags: ruby, net-ftp

I have a remote ftp server.
I can connect to it with CyberDuck or terminal ftp client.

When trying to connect with `Net::FTP` I can do this:

```
ftp=Net::FTP.new
ftp.connect('url', 'port')
ftp.login('username', 'password')
```

However, doing this:

```
Net::FTP.open('url', 'username', 'password')
```

returns `Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2)`.

It seems like `.open` doesn't accept a port parameter, resulting in an error for me since I use custom port. But I need to use `.open` method, because it's used in external gem I use (`carrierwave-webdav`).
Any workaround for this one or should I create my own fork?
How can I connect to my ftp using `.open` method?

Answer (score 4):

<strike>If you pass *host* argument to `Net::FTP.new` or mandatory to `Net::FTP.open` it tries to connect immediately so you have to pass non-standard port number in other way like passing together with a hostname:</strike>

<strike>Net::FTP.open('url:port', 'username', 'password')</strike>

**UPDATE:**
Ruby net library unfortunately doesn't parse host string so you need perform all connection steps separately:

```
ftp = Net::FTP.new  # don't pass hostname or it will try open on default port
ftp.connect('url', port)  # here you can pass a non-standard port number
ftp.login('username', 'password')
ftp.passive = true  # optional, if PASV mode is required
```

Comment: I always get `SocketError: getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known` when I include the `:`.

Answer (score 2):

The @jackbot's answer is correct, and sample code for setting `FTP_PORT` is very simple:

```
Net::FTP.send(:remove_const, 'FTP_PORT') # just to avoid warnings
Net::FTP.const_set('FTP_PORT', 22222)
```

where 22222 is new ftp port.

The full chain is: `open` calls `new`, which calls `connect`, which uses `FTP_PORT`. You can look at source code here:  http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Net/FTP.html#method-c-new.

Answer (score 1):

It seems `Net::FTP::open` calls `Net::FTP::connect` under the hood, which connects to a port [set in the `FTP_PORT` constant](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/net/ftp/rdoc/Net/FTP.html#method-i-connect). It's not a very nice solution but you could set that constant to the port you need.